# Change empty values to NaN in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I have a Javascript array.

```
var myarray = ["100", "200", "", ""];
```

I am trying to change all blank values in the array to Number.NaN.

I can find examples online to change falsey values to 0, but I am not sure how to do it the other way around?

Comment: Empty strings are not `null`.  I suggest you edit your title, it's misleading and incorrect. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have update the title

Comment: do you have only strings in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using map function

```
const newArray=myarray.map(no=>{return parseInt(no)})
```

Comment: `parseInt` should have a radix argument.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: This doesn't work, the values in the array still show as "100",  "200", "", ""

Comment: @user3580480" He gave an incomplete example and no explanation. What map does is it creates a new array based on the values of the original, and returns that array. So you need to assign its result to a variable. `const newArray = myarray.map(...)`

Answer (score 1):

By having only strings, you could map with a default value.

```js
var array = ["100", "200", "", ""];

array = array.map(v => v || NaN);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change all the empty strings in your existing array *in place* to `NaN`, you can loop over the elements of the array:

```js
var myarray = ["100", "200", "", ""];

for (let i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
  if (myarray[i] === "") {
    myarray[i] = NaN;
  }
}

console.log(myarray);
```

To return a *new array* with the empty strings replaced by `NaN`, you can use `Array.map`:

```js
var myarray = ["100", "200", "", ""];

const newArray = myarray.map(el => el === "" ? NaN : el);

console.log(newArray);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map